# How do I know from whe warning in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Now I'm getting these messages, but I have not even used

```
refs
```

in my 
code

[image]

Comment: Well what's your code look like? And please no pictures. Also, can you clarify question?

Comment: The warning is pretty straightforward? The React devs want you to use `findDomNode` from`react-dom` instead of from the main `react` library. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using react 0.14 and you can't do `React.findDOMNode` anymore. You need to use **ReactDOM** from `react-dom` package `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`. Looking at the top of your warning point's you to the right direction.